# Mysql IF statement in SELECT clause?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to include an `IF` on my `SELECT` statement, while defining a temporary column.

This is what I'm trying right now:

```
SELECT *, IF A > 0, A, 0.5 AS Popularity FROM Visits
```

How is it correctly done?

Answer (score 3):

You want to do :

```
SELECT *, IF (A > 0, A, 0.5) AS Popularity FROM Visits
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the IF syntax used in stored procedures. For SELECT use, it has to be the [function version](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT *, IF(A>0, A, 0.5) AS Popularity ...
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that works in other DBMSes is

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( a > 0 ) THEN a ELSE 0.5 END AS popularity FROM visits
```